# How do we know that the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$ exists as $n$ increases without bound?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am starting to learn Calculus now and my learning pathway for finding the derivatives of exponentials and logarithms goes like this:

1. I assume that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n=e$. I accept this by definition.
2. Then, I do all the necessary computations to prove other stuffs from it.

Here, I am confused about two things:

1. Why would such a limit even exist? Well, you can show me the graph of the function but still that does not explain in a proper way why it exists  ( It shows how that exists ).
2. Why is $\lim_{n\to-\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$  ?

Comment: 1. What function are you talking about ?

2. Rewrite $(1+1/n)^n= \exp(n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))$. Notice that $n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$ is a quotient difference : $n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})- \ln(1+0) }{\frac{1}{n}-0}$  to compute its limit when $n\to+\infty$

Comment: Have you seen that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$? Also, there is a typo in (2.), the minus sign is misplaced.

Comment: Your second question is equivalent to $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-(1/n))^{-n}$. This can be established by proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-(1/n^2))^n=1$ which gives us $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+(1/n))^n}{(1-(1/n))^{-n}}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that the sequence is monotone and bounded. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete this gives you the convergence. The second thing is really just by definition. You define $e$ to be that limit and everything else you know about $e$ has to be shown using that definition of $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in calculus, I assume you  haven't gone through real analysis, but to give you a satisfactory answer, I need to introduce you  the definition of limit of a sequence. Now what does it mean for a limit of a sequence to exists or a sequence converging to a number (which we say the limit of sequence)? They say for any real sequence $(x_n)$ to converge to a real number $x$, there must exist a natural number $k$ for a given $\epsilon> 0$ (as small as we please!), such that for all $n\geq k$, the terms $x_n$ satisfies $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$.

In other words, if I claim that a sequence is converging to some number or its limit exists, then whatever **positive** value of $\epsilon$ you put in front of me, I can always locate the term in the sequence, after which the **distance** between the terms and the proposed limit is always less than your given value of $\epsilon$.

This is the fundamental definition of limit of a sequence. Related to this there's another theorem, by which we can indirectly claim a sequence is convergent or its limit exists. It says that, if any sequence is monotonically increasing or decreasing **and** is bounded, then it must be converging.  *Note that only bounded sequence doesn't imply convergence, for example, oscillatory sequence could be bounded but they are not convergent*.  We will use this here.

Coming back to your problem, we consider the sequence $e_n= \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We will show that the sequence is bounded and increasing, and hence is convergent or limit exists. Applying Binomial Theorem, we have

$e_n= \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n= 1+\dfrac{n}{1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n^3}+\cdots+\dfrac{n(n-1)\ldots2\cdot 1}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^n}$

If we divide the powers of $n$ into the terms in the numerators of binomial coefficients, we get

$e_n= 1+1+\dfrac{1}{2!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)+\dfrac{1}{3!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)$

Similarly we have

$e_{n+1}= 1+1+\dfrac{1}{2!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\dfrac{1}{3!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n+1}\right)+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n+1}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}\right)+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n+1}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)$

Note that $e_{n}$ contains $n+1$ terms while $e_{n+1}$ contains $n+2$ terms. Moreover each term appearing in $e_n$ is less than or equal to the corresponding term in $e_{n+1}$, and $e_{n+1}$ has one more positive term. Therefore we have $2\leq e_1< e_2< \cdots< e_n< e_{n+1}< \cdots,$ so the terms of $(e_n)$ are increasing.

To show that the terms of $(e_n)$ is bounded above, we note that if $p= 1, 2, \ldots, n$ then $(1-p/n)< 1$. Moreover $2^{p-1}\leq p!$, so $1/p!\leq 1/2^{p-1}$. Therefore if $n> 1$ then we have

$2< e_n< 1+1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Since it can be verified that $ 1+1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}= 1-\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}< 1$, we deduce that $2< e_n< 3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus its bounded and increasing implies convergent limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

We have :
$$ \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{n\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} $$
So the limit when $n$ tend to $+\infty$ is :
$$\begin{align} 
\lim_{n\to +\infty} e^{n\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}&=\lim_{n\to +\infty} e^{n \times \frac{1}{n}}\\
&=e^1\\
&=e
\end{align}$$
Let me explain what I've done, you'll wonder why did I replaced $\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ with $\frac{1}{n}$, (I'm assuming you're new to the natural logarithm, sorry if you found my explanation basic) :
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}=\frac{\mathrm{d} \ln x}{\mathrm{d}x}\Bigg\vert_{x=1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$
So when $x$ is close to $0$ we have :
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}=1\Longleftrightarrow \ln(x)\sim x-1 $$
Substituting $x-1=t$ we'll obtain :
$$\ln(1+t)\overset{t\to 0}{\sim} t$$
In this example you have :
$$\lim \ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
when $n \to \infty \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ so :
$$\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim \frac{1}{n}$$
And I replaced it in the limit and hence the result. I'm assuming that's the only thing you don't understand.\
Generally you may think of this as a technique to evaluate limits :
$$\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)\sim f(x)$$
But pay attention you have to verify that :
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}1+f(x) =1$$

Answer (score 0):

Use AM-GM to prove that
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

Now, give it any bound, let's say $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<3$. Now, argue using monotone convergence.

Answer (score 0):

See suppose you have a function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$
Now at $x=0$, $f(x)=\frac{\sin 0}{0}$ which does not have any meaning because $f(x)$ can't be defined at $x=0$. But what if $x=10^{-50}$? $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ but it can be defined at $x=10^{-50}$. Now, if we see the graph of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ we see as $x$ is going near to $0$, the value of $f(x)$ goes near to $1$. That does not mean $f(x)=1$. Thus we say limit exists for $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $0$. Limits is an important concept, which helps to define derivative.

As for your second question, $e$ is defined like that. This is definition of $e$ and all other properties of $e$ come from this definition.

Answer (score 0):

Expand by the Binomial theorem, it is
$$1+{n\choose1}\frac1n+{n\choose2}\left(\frac1n\right)^2+...\\
=1+\frac nn+\frac12\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}+...$$
Each term is $1/k!$ times a fraction that increases to 1.
For the second question $1-1/n$ is close to the reciprocal of $1+1/n$ when $n$ gets large.  For example,$1.01×0.99=0.9999$ is very close to 1. So $(1-1/n)^{-n}=1/(1-1/n)^n$ is close to $(1+1/n)^n$